# Awk command unexpected newline or end of string

Tags: awk, newline, ksh

I'm trying to find what sort of value in ${RESULT} as used in this script;

```
#!/bin/ksh
...
echo ${RESULT}|awk '{if ($0 ~ /RUNNING mode/) {print "STATUS=0"; print "PID="'${PID}'; print "INFO="$0; print '$PID' > "'${INSTALLDIR}/domain'/sample_pid.txt"} else {print "STATUS=1"; print "PID=-1"; print "INFO="$0} }'
```

Could cause this output:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {if ($0 ~ /RUNNING mode/) {print "STATUS=0"; print "PID="27708
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                              ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

I've tried throwing many combinations of special characters into ${RESULT} and it never has issues.  I'll probably rewrite the command anyway but I am curious about what ${RESULT} could be both as an educational point and also to help me reproduce the error that was reported to me from a test system, which I haven't otherwise been able to reproduce.

Thanks!

Comment: You can easily debug it. Use the standard way to pass shell variables to awk, not like this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script `-v pid="$PID"` etc

Answer (score 4):

Your code has issues with how to call shell variables in `awk` + redundant use of functions (e.g. `print`). Keeping `awk` code like `awk '.........' Input_file` is what is recommended. You could take the following as a start, but since no samples were given, I have not tested it at all; it's completely based on the attempt by OP.

Also whenever you are writing output to a output file it's better to place output file name in `(output file name)`

```
echo "$RESULT" | 
awk -v installdir="${INSTALLDIR}/domain" -v pid="$PID" -v outfile="sample_pid.txt" '
{
  if ($0 ~ /RUNNING mode/){
     print "STATUS=0\nPID=" pid "\nINFO="$0 >  (installdir"/"pid"/"outfile)
  }
  else{
     print "STATUS=1\nPID=-1\nINFO="$0
  }
}'
```